# Identify and replace using regex some strings, stored within a list, within a string that may or may not contain them

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace, regex-group

```py
import re

#list of names to identify in input strings
result_list = ['Thomas Edd', 'Melissa Clark', 'Ada White', 'Louis Pasteur', 'Edd Thomas', 'Clark Melissa', 'White Eda', 'Pasteur Louis', 'Thomas', 'Melissa', 'Ada', 'Louis', 'Edd', 'Clark', 'White', 'Pasteur']

result_list.sort() # sorts normally by alphabetical order (optional)
result_list.sort(key=len, reverse=True) # sorts by descending length

#example 1
input_text = "Melissa went for a walk in the park, then Melisa Clark went to the cosmetics store. There Thomas showed her a wide variety of cosmetic products. Edd Thomas is a great salesman, even so Thomas Edd is a skilled but responsible salesman, as Edd is always honest with his customers. White is a new client who came to Edd's business due to the good social media reviews she saw from Melissa, her co-worker."

#In this example 2, it is almost the same however, some of the names were already encapsulated
# under the ((PERS)name) structure, and should not be encapsulated again.
input_text = "((PERS)Melissa) went for a walk in the park, then Melisa Clark went to the cosmetics store. There Thomas showed her a wide variety of cosmetic products. Edd Thomas is a great salesman, even so ((PERS)Thomas Edd) is a skilled but responsible salesman, as Edd is always honest with his customers. White is a new client who came to Edd's business due to the good social media reviews she saw from Melissa, her co-worker." #example 1

for i in result_list:
    input_text = re.sub(r"\(\(PERS\)" + r"(" + str(i) + r")" + r"\)",
                        lambda m: (f"((PERS){m[1]})"),
                        input_text)


print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

Note that the names meet certain conditions under which they must be identified, that is, they must be in the middle of 2 whitespaces `\s*the searched name\s*` or be at the beginning `(?:(?<=\s)|^)` or/and at the end of the input string.

It may also be the case that a name is followed by a comma, for example `"Ada White, Melissa and Louis went shopping"` or if spaces are accidentally omitted `"Ada White,Melissa and Louis went shopping"`.
For this reason it is important that after `[.,;]` the possibility that it does find a name.

Cases where the names should NOT be encapsulated, would be for example...

`"the Edd's business"`

`"The whitespace"`

`"the pasteurization process takes time"`

`"Those White-spaces in that text are unnecessary"`

, since in these cases the name is followed or preceded by another word that should not be part of the name that is being searched for.

For examples 1 and 2 (note that example 2 is the same as example 1 but already has some encapsulated names and you have to prevent them from being encapsulated again), you should get the following output.

```
"((PERS)Melissa) went for a walk in the park, then ((PERS)Melisa Clark) went to the cosmetics store. There ((PERS)Thomas) showed her a wide variety of cosmetic products. ((PERS)Edd Thomas) is a great salesman, even so ((PERS)Thomas Edd) is a skilled but responsible salesman, as ((PERS)Edd) is always honest with his customers. ((PERS)White) is a new client who came to Edd's business due to the good social media reviews she saw from ((PERS)Melissa), her co-worker."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookarounds to exclude already encapsulated names and those followed by `'`, an alphanumeric character or `-`:

```py
import re

result_list = ['Thomas Edd', 'Melissa Clark', 'Ada White', 'Louis Pasteur', 'Edd Thomas', 'Clark Melissa', 'White Eda', 'Pasteur Louis', 'Thomas', 'Melissa', 'Ada', 'Louis', 'Edd', 'Clark', 'White', 'Pasteur']
result_list.sort(key=len, reverse=True) # sorts by descending length

input_text = "((PERS)Melissa) went for a walk in the park, then Melissa Clark went to the cosmetics store. There Thomas showed her a wide variety of cosmetic products. Edd Thomas is a great salesman, even so ((PERS)Thomas Edd) is a skilled but responsible salesman, as Edd is always honest with his customers. White is a new client who came to Edd's business due to the good social media reviews she saw from Melissa, her co-worker." #example 1

pat = re.compile(rf"(?<!\(PERS\))({'|'.join(result_list)})(?!['\w)-])")
input_text = re.sub(pat, r'((PERS)\1)', input_text)
```

Output:

```
((PERS)Melissa) went for a walk in the park, then ((PERS)Melissa Clark) went to the cosmetics store. There ((PERS)Thomas) showed her a wide variety of cosmetic products. ((PERS)Edd Thomas) is a great salesman, even so ((PERS)Thomas Edd) is a skilled but responsible salesman, as ((PERS)Edd) is always honest with his customers. ((PERS)White) is a new client who came to Edd's business due to the good social media reviews she saw from ((PERS)Melissa), her co-worker.
```

Of course you can refine the content of your lookahead based on further edge cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, this identification pattern worked perfectly for me

Comment: You're welcome! I just noticed that the loop is useless here. I fixed the code

Comment: Thanks for editing it, now I assume that the code should be more optimized avoiding entering even a loop, which repeats the process as many times as the elements in the list. Have you been able to skip the `for i in result_list:` loop, because the `.join()` already loops through the list of names `result_list` in the correct order automatically?

Comment: Yes, '|'.join() joins all list elements with `|`, which is 'OR' in a regex pattern